# I am getting SSLCertVerificationError while doing web Scraping

Tags: python, machine-learning, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, data-science

```
def scrape_wikipedia(name_topic, verbose=True):
def link_to_wikipedia(link):
    try:
        page = api_wikipedia.page(link)
        if page.exists():
            return {'page': link, 'text': page.text, 'link': page.fullurl, 'categories': list(page.categories.keys())}
    except:
        return None
  
api_wikipedia = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia(language='en', extract_format=wikipediaapi.ExtractFormat.WIKI)
name_of_page = api_wikipedia.page(name_topic)
if not name_of_page.exists():
    print('Page {} is not present'.format(name_of_page))
    return

links_to_page = list(name_of_page.links.keys())
procceed = tqdm(desc='Scraped links', unit='', total=len(links_to_page)) if verbose else None
origin = [{'page': name_topic, 'text': name_of_page.text, 'link': name_of_page.fullurl, 'categories': list(name_of_page.categories.keys())}]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    links_future = {executor.submit(link_to_wikipedia, link): link for link in links_to_page}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(links_future):
        info = future.result()
        origin.append(info) if info else None
        procceed.update(1) if verbose else None
procceed.close() if verbose else None

namespaces = ('Wikipedia', 'Special', 'Talk', 'LyricWiki', 'File', 'MediaWiki',
             'Template', 'Help', 'User', 'Category talk', 'Portal talk')
origin = pds.DataFrame(origin)
origin = origin[(len(origin['text']) > 20)
                 & ~(origin['page'].str.startswith(namespaces, na=True))]
origin['categories'] = origin.categories.apply(lambda a: [b[9:] for b in a])

origin['topic'] = name_topic
print('Scraped pages', len(origin))

return origin
```

`SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=COVID+19&inprop=protection%7Ctalkid%7Cwatched%7Cwatchers%7Cvisitingwatchers%7Cnotificationtimestamp%7Csubjectid%7Curl%7Creadable%7Cpreload%7Cdisplaytitle&format=json&redirects=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

Answer (score 0):

Python would use the system provided certificate database on all platforms. Failure to locate such a database would be an error, and you would need to explicitly specify a location to fix it. If you want to know more on why you had that bug click [Python Enhancement Proposals](https://peps.python.org/pep-0476/)

Try adding this two lines of code in to your python Script.

```py
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: I tried adding these two lines and followed  Python Enhancement Proposals but still, my issue is not resolved, I can run my script on a window machine but am facing an issue on a Mac machine.
could you please tell me where to add these two lines, I tried adding in a custom function which I have defined?

Comment: Add it in your function `def link_to_wikipedia(link):` and also indent the rest of your code under `def scrape_wikipedia(name_topic, verbose=True):` the way you have it in your question is not properly indented.

Comment: The entire code still need some indentation refracturing, I couldn't edit it anymore because the `edit request` is full, but you been the author, you can edit it at any time.